# Weird iframe width bug on facebook embed code

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, facebook-iframe

I am trying to embed facebook reviews on my website,
but the width of the box doesn't appear right.
width: 286px, it Loads the default 350px;

[image: 1]

Interestingly when I open the Developer Console and reload the page, the iframe loads perfectly with the exact size it should be.

I also tried to write jquery script that reloads the iframe after page is rendered but with no success.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and how I could fix it?
Thank you

```
                            <div class="container">
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <div class="card" style="width: 286px; height:215px;">
                                          <iframe onload="reloadOnce(this)" width="286px" height="215px" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fkirsty.armstrong.904%2Fposts%2F2292031390876127&width=286" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <div class="card" style="width: 286px; height:215px;">
                                          <iframe onload="reloadOnce(this)" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Faneesa.aidroos.3%2Fposts%2F386560588794579&width=286" width="286px" height="215px" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <div class="card" style="width: 286px; height:215px;">
                                          <iframe onload="reloadOnce(this)" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Falinbush%2Fposts%2F2343483609028644&width=286" width="286px" height="215px" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
```

[image: 2]

Comment: Facebook gives option to use `small`, `large`, etc into their data variable to manage this width. You'll find the possible values on their official developer website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook requires minimum 350px width.